# Ruby Insert Parameter Into Regexp Match

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm defining a method where I am trying to match up a string with a compound match string, where a parameter is inserted into that match string:

```
def dingbat(a, searchString)
    m = searchString.match(/<td>/ + a + /<\/td><td>(.+)<\/td>/)

    return m
end
```

Any insight appreciated.  I'm new to Ruby.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can either

```
/<td>/#{a}/<\/td><td>(.+)<\/td>/.match(searchString)
```

or

```
searchString.match(/<td>/#{a}/<\/td><td>(.+)<\/td>/)
```

Arbitrary Ruby expressions can be embedded into patterns with the #{...} construct.

Comment: The match isn't actually necessarily backwards, `str.match(regex)` and `regex.match(str)` are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You want to interpolate a variable in the regex.

```
m = searchString.match(/<td>#{a}<\/td><td>(.+)<\/td>/)
```

adding #{your variable} in the regex should work.